# Do Kant or Aristotle ever comment on the line between self-interest/preservation and helping others?

Tags: ethics, kant, aristotle, metaethics, deontology

Im wondering whether either of them ever talked about limits to helping others and when we should choose ourselves.
Ive tried doing some research but unfortunately to not avail.

Comment: Maybe focus on just Aristotle or Kant (or open a question for each). Or are you asking how their views compare?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question is too broad for our format. Please narrow not only by philosopher, but perhaps by a subset of the notion of selfishness vs. altruism.